# How do I count characters in a string, excluding certain types?

Tags: string, delphi, counting

I need to determine the total number of characters in a textbox and display the value in a label, but all whitespace need to be excluded.

Here is the code:

```
var     
sLength : string;
i : integer;
begin
     sLength := edtTheText.Text;
     slength:= ' ';
     i := length(sLength);

     //display the length of the string
     lblLength.Caption := 'The string is ' +  IntToStr(i)  + ' characters long';
```

Comment: Do you want all whitespaces removed? For instance, tabs as well as spaces?

Comment: I would like all the blank spaces removed.

Comment: honestly, this question is pretty easy.  Have you even tried?

Comment: Just as info: The code you've posted makes no sense. You assign the contents of `edtTheText.Text` to `sLength`, and then on the very next line you assign a blank space instead (`sLength:= ' ';`). The second assignment would make the length of `sLength` always 1 (unless you then remove the blank space, in which case it would always be 0).

Comment: Hi Glutz, I have tried it, but have only being using Delphi for a week and half now so very new to it.

Comment: Determine the string length works.

Comment: OK, but what about the question. Determining the length, excluding whitespace? Does my answer solve your problem?

Comment: Hi David, I tried your solution but I get an error with Character.IsWhiteSpace ( undeclared undentifier) . I am using delphi 2010.

Comment: You missed the part of the answer where you need to add a reference to the `Character` unit. The first two lines of code in my answer. Add those, or more likely add `Character` to the existing `uses` clause at the top of the unit.

Comment: Thanks David all is now working.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can count the non-white space characters like this:

```
uses
  Character;

function NonWhiteSpaceCharacterCount(const str: string): Integer;
var
  c: Char;
begin
  Result := 0;
  for c in str do
    if not Character.IsWhiteSpace(c) then
      inc(Result);
end;
```

This uses [`Character.IsWhiteSpace`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Character.IsWhiteSpace) to determine whether or not a character is whitespace. `IsWhiteSpace` returns `True` if and only if the character is classified as being whitespace, according to the Unicode specification. So, tab characters count as whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an Ansi version of Delphi you can also use a Lookup Table with something like

```
NotBlanks: Array[0..255] Of Boolean
```

A Bool in the array is set if the matching character is not a blank. Then In the loop you simply increment your counter

```
Count := 0;
For i := 1 To Length(MyStringToParse) Do
  Inc(Count, Byte(NotBlanks[ Ord(MyStringToParse[i]])) );
```

In the same fashion you can use a set:

```
For i := 1 To Length(MyStringToParse) Do
If Not (MyStringToParse[i] In [#1,#2{define the blanks in this enum}]) Then 
  Inc(Count).
```

Actually you have many ways to solve this.